# Kafka stores log4j logs in directory literally called ${kafka.logs.dir}

Tags: java, systemd, kafka, rhel8, log4j

I installed a preview version of Kafka 3.0 with log4j2 support ([http://home.apache.org/~dongjin/post/apache-kafka-log4j2-support/](http://home.apache.org/%7Edongjin/post/apache-kafka-log4j2-support/)) on a RHEL 8 server. Kafka and Zookeeper are running successfully as systemd user services. I set the environment variable `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/home/username/kafka/bin/../config/log4j2.properties"` in the systemd unit file so that log4j 2.17 ist used.

However, there is one strange thing: all log4j logs are stored in a directory literally called `${kafka.logs.dir}` in the home directory. The garbage collector successfully stores logs in the correct log location `~/kafka/logs`. So the directory `~/kafka/logs` contains files like `kafkaServer-gc.log.0.current`, while the hilariously strange directory `~/${kafka.logs.dir}` contains `server.log`, `controller.log`, etc.

When looking at the processes for kafka and zookeeper, I can see that they both have the argument `-Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/username/kafka/bin/../logs`. Shouldn't this define the environment variable `kafka.logs.dir`, which is used in the file `config/log4j2.properties`? How come that Zookeeper and Kafka apparently don't have access to this `$kafka.logs.dir` environment variable?

Comment: Result of disabled pattern substitution due to Log4shell fixes?

Comment: You're probably right. I added a definition of kafka.logs.dir to the beginning of log4j2.properties with the directory path and it still used `${kafka.logs.dir}` as directory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `sys:` prefix to the `kafka.logs.dir` system variable in the `log4j2.properties` file. That is:

- AS-IS: `${kafka.logs.dir}`
- TO-BE: `${sys:kafka.logs.dir}`

DISCLAIMER: As you can see in my name, I wrote this code (log4j2 migration of Apache Kafka) and am maintaining [the preview build](http://home.apache.org/%7Edongjin/post/apache-kafka-log4j2-support/). The fix will be released soon. Sorry for being late.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for this log4j2 migration. It's been working really well all things considered

Comment: I just released preview versions fixing this issue, based on 3.0.1, 3.1.1, and 3.2.0. Please have a look at the webpage.

Comment: Yep, that solved the issue. Thanks!